# Subdomain to specific rout app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I wanna make that a subdomain points to a specific url in my custom domain in app engine, just like this:

sub.domain.com => domain.com/sub

i'm using DomainRoute in my code and publish in production but, didn't work

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    routes.DomainRoute('mySub.domain.com', [
            webapp2.Route('/mobile', handler=ConoceMas, name='mobile-landing'),
        ]),
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/(es|en|fr|de)', MainPage),
    ('/sendcomments', SendComments),
    ('/subscribe', Subscribe),
    ('/mobile', ConoceMas)
```

When i put ANY subdomains go to the main page.

What's wrong with this code? and how can prove it in the localhost environment?

PS.
In the domain mask i put the * CNAME config (in godaddy admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i follow this steps to solve this:

1. add the subdomain in the CNAME alias in goddady
2. add the subdomain in the app engine [console](http://console.developers.google.com/project)
3. modify mycode to this

> 

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
routes.DomainRoute('mySub.domain.com', [
        webapp2.Route('/', handler=ConoceMas, name='mobile-landing'), 
    ])    #entry point of the subdomain
routes.DomainRoute('mySub.domain.com', [
        webapp2.Route('/(es|en|fr|de)', handler=ConoceMas, name='mobile-landing'), 
    ]),  #entry point of the subdomain with parameters
('/', MainPage),
('/(es|en|fr|de)', MainPage),
('/sendcomments', SendComments),
('/subscribe', Subscribe),
('/mobile', ConoceMas)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your domain with App Engine first? it's explained pretty clearly [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain), and when I actually had to link something to my custom domain, the redirects worked fine.

Comment: the custom domains works fine, if i goes to my browser and see http://myDomains.com works, also if a go to http://myDomains.com/Sub but i wanna type http://MySub.MyDomains.com and be handled by http://myDomains.com/Sub

Comment: You going to your browser and making it work doesn't mean App Engine will recognize it (this might not be your issue now, but you definitely will have to make it "known" to App Engine), and this process will need to be done.

Comment: routes.DomainRoute doesn't do this stuff?

Comment: not 100% sure. I didn't go that route to do it (couldn't help the bad pun, sorry :P). I registered it and then used the standard configuration documents (app.yaml or web.xml) to do the routing